# Error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous - Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, logic

I know this question has been asked before, however, when I am trying to do an `if` statement and I am getting an error. I looked at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o) , but did not help much in my case. My `dfs` is a list of DataFrames.

I am trying the following,

```
for i in dfs:
    if (i['var1'] < 3.000):
       print(i)
```

Gives the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

**AND** I tried the following and getting the same error.

```
for i,j in enumerate(dfs):
    if (j['var1'] < 3.000):
       print(i)
```

My `var1` data type is `float32`. I am not using any other `logical` operators and `&` or `|`. In the above link it seemed to be because of using logical operators. Why do I get `ValueError`?

Comment: do all DFs in the list have only one row?

Comment: When should `if` be true? From the moment there is at least one such row? Or from the moment all values are less than 3?

Comment: in this case it's not clear - what are you comparing in the `if ...`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `if` should be `true` when `var1` is less than 3.

Comment: @i.n.n.m, do you realize that your comparison is very similar to `[1,2,3,4,5] > 2`? What result do you expect?

Comment: @i.n.n.m: but `var1` is a column, so it can contains 1000s of elements.

Comment: @MaxU I am comparing `var1`. If the value of `var1` column has a value less than 3, then I would like to get the index of that `df`

Comment: @i.n.n.m, the value of `var1` is a __Series__ (list alike object or vector)

Comment: @MaxU `[1,2,3,4,5] > 2` in this case, I can not compare a list to `2`. Is that something I am trying to do in my code? When I do it for a single `df` it returns `True` or `False` though

Comment: @i.n.n.m `i` is a dataframe, so `i['var1']` is a Series.  As @MaxU said, this is equivalent to comparing each element in the series to your value, e.g. `[1 < 3, 2 < 3, 3 < 3, 4 < 3, 5 < 3]`.  The result is an identically shaped series with the result of each comparison, `[True, True, False, False, False]`

Comment: @i.n.n.m, exactly !

Comment: @i.n.n.m there is disconnect with the terms you are using and the results we see.  We cannot reconcile these differences unless you help us by **showing** us the data, your code, and what you are trying to get.  This is the spirit of providing a minimal, complete, and verifiable example or [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @i.n.n.m, i'm pretty sure you would find it out yourself when trying to show a desired data set ;-) Please listen to piRSquared - this will save your and our time. Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @MaxU yes, i figured it already, thank you for asking the right questions to make me understand.

Comment: "I looked at this link , but did not help much in my case." - it's been continually improved over the years, and it definitely covers this case thoroughly now. The short explanation of the original complaint is that `if` fails in the same situations where `and` and `or` would fail, **for the same reason**. It's *boolean logic* that therefore cares about the *truth value* of the Series - *just like the error message mentions*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a small demo, which shows why this is happenning:

```
In [131]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,20,(5,2)), columns=list('AB'))

In [132]: df
Out[132]:
    A   B
0   3  11
1   0  16
2  16   1
3   2  11
4  18  15

In [133]: res = df['A'] > 10

In [134]: res
Out[134]:
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

when we try to check whether such Series is `True` - Pandas doesn't know what to do:

```
In [135]: if res:
     ...:     print(df)
     ...:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
...
skipped
...
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Workarounds:

we can decide how to treat Series of boolean values - for example `if` should return `True` if **all** values are `True`:

```
In [136]: res.all()
Out[136]: False
```

or when **at least one** value is True:

```
In [137]: res.any()
Out[137]: True

In [138]: if res.any():
     ...:     print(df)
     ...:
    A   B
0   3  11
1   0  16
2  16   1
3   2  11
4  18  15
```

Answer (score 4):

Currently, you're selecting the entire series for comparison. To get an individual value from the series, you'll want to use something along the lines of:

```
for i in dfs:
if (i['var1'].iloc[0] < 3.000):
   print(i)
```

To compare each of the individual elements you can use [series.iteritems](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html) (documentation is sparse on this one) like so:

```
for i in dfs:
    for _, v in i['var1'].iteritems():
        if v < 3.000:
            print(v)
```

The better solution here for most cases is to select a subset of the dataframe to use for whatever you need, like so:

```
for i in dfs:
    subset = i[i['var1'] < 3.000]
    # do something with the subset
```

Performance in pandas is much faster on large dataframes when using series operations instead of iterating over individual values. For more detail, you can check out the pandas [documentation on selection.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Answer (score 2):

the comparison returns a range of values, you need to limit it either by any() or all(), for example,

```
     if((df[col] == ' this is any string or list').any()):
       return(df.loc[df[col] == temp].index.values.astype(int)[0])
```